# SQL Server 2012: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I get this error when running this query...

```
select *, stuff(PartNumber,1,3,'') 
from products.products 
where  isnumeric(stuff(partNumber,1,3,'') 
order by cast(Stuff(partNumber,1,3,'')As Float)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `where` statement is incomplete:

```
where  isnumeric(stuff(partNumber,1,3,'')) = 1
-----------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a parentheses:

This:

```
where  isnumeric(stuff(partNumber,1,3,'')
```

Should be:

```
where  isnumeric(stuff(partNumber,1,3,''))
```

Answer (score 1):

First is you are missing the closed bracket ")" and another is you have to assign in where clause the isnumeric  returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type.

```
   `    select *, stuff(PartNumber,1,3,'') 
        from products.products 
      where  isnumeric(stuff(partNumber,1,3,'')) =1
     order by cast(Stuff(partNumber,1,3,'') As Float)
  `
```